# How to calculate datediff with dates from several columns in correct order?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have three columns for three different status: clicked, claimed, and bought.

I want to calculate the number of days from the deadline date to the clicked date. HOWEVER, if the clicked date is not found (meaning it is set to: '2999-12-31') then take the deadline date - claimed date. If the clicked date and the claimed date are set to '2999-12-31' then subtract deadline_date - bought_date. Also if the deadline_date is NULL, set the number of days as 0.

So the order should be always if deadline is NULL, set number_days to 0. Otherwise, subtract deadline_date MINUS clicked_date, unless clicked is not found, then use CLAIMED to subtract. If clicked and claimed is not found, then subtract BOUGHT from deadline.

I tried the query below, but it doesn't work when I need to subtract deadline_date - bought_date.

```
select 
ID,
   CASE when DEADLINE_DATE IS NULL then 0
        WHEN clicked_date <> '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' THEN DATEDIFF('days', clicked_date,deadline_date) 
        when clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' THEN DATEDIFF('days', claimed_date,deadline_date)
        when clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' and claimed_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' THEN DATEDIFF('days', bought_date,deadline_date)
       when clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' and clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000'  and bought_date  <> '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' 
       THEN DATEDIFF('days', bought_date,deadline_date)   
    END AS number_days
from TBL_A a
group by 1
order by number_days
```

Comment: should  be a combination of `case` or `iff` statements and substitution by using `ifnull`

Comment: why do you keep asking the same question, and provide zero feedback about what you do not understand on your prior questions.

Comment: Or possible better stop using  '2999-12-31' as a magic date, and explain what you reall want the outcome to be, (you really should be use null for the "magic value" as there is a many tools for dealing with that).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deal with complex queries is to visualize what is happening and why.

You can create a second column with the same conditions, but as a result indicate on which branch of conditions the calculation went. This will help you deal with the problem yourself, and not only in this case.

It is not always possible to say unambiguously how a particular database engine behaves when working with NULL values, so create something like a check column.

```
CASE when DEADLINE_DATE IS NULL then 0
        WHEN clicked_date <> '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' THEN 1
        when clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' THEN 2
        when clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' and claimed_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' THEN 3
       when clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' and clicked_date = '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000'  and bought_date  <> '2999-12-31 23:59:05.000' 
       THEN 4
    END AS the_calculation_check_column
```

Comment: This is actually a good suggestion.

Comment: @VKU  Problem is, it'll never be 3 or 4 as it's now. You see, a `CASE WHEN` completes as soon a condition is true. So it'll end with 2 before considering 3 or 4

Comment: @LukStorms I think the author of the post will be happy to independently understand why 3 and 4 will never come. He may also want to put the second case after the fourth. The best experience is experiment.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    zeroifnull(
            datediff(
                day,
                  coalesce( 
                      NULLIF( clicked_date ,'2999-01-01') 
                     ,NULLIF( bought_date  ,'2999-01-01') 
                     ,NULLIF( claimed_date ,'2999-01-01') 
                    )
                 ,NULLIF( deadline_date , '2999-01-01')
                    )
            )
from 
   your_table
```